# Drupal on mysql cluster

Tags: drupal, savepoints

when I put set the `ENGINE=NDBCLUSTER` of all the tables of the drupal and I edit and save the block in the drupal, there is problem about `savepoint`.

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.1
>   array ( '%type' => 'PDOException', '!message' => 'SQLSTATE[42000]:
>   Syntax error or access violation: 1178 The storage engine for the
>   table doesn't support SAVEPOINT: SAVEPOINT savepoint_1; Array ( ) ',
>   '%function' => 'block_admin_configure_submit()', '%file' =>
>   '/opt/lampp/htdocs/geosquare/modules/block/block.admin.inc', '%line'
>   => 504, 'severity_level' => 3, )

I have tried to change the `ENGINE=MyISAM` which does not support `SAVEPOINT` either, but when i edit and save the block of the drupal.

It works fine. It confused me for a while, wish for a help.

Comment: any update in this regard?